# Sequential setter calls with new values only result in 1 multi-dependency useEffect call

Tags: reactjs

I have a `useEffect` which watches for any changes in 2 dependency variables, `step` and `reviewElementId`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    //...
}, [step, reviewElementId]);
```

There is a function which changes both of these variables sequentially, as follows:

```
const update = () => {

    setStep(..);      
    //...
    setReviewElementId(..);

}
```

**The new values are both different from the original values**.

My debugger shows that the useEffect is **called only once**, which doesn't make sense to me. I expect it to be called twice, in succession, due to the two variable updates, one per each, which are both different from before.

I understand that nothing will happen when the variable is the same; but even when both are different, the debugger only shows a single call to useEffect.

One note: In that single Effect call, I see that **both** variables are updated already.

Comment: You're probably experiencing [batching](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates). React 18 _waits until all code in the event handlers has run before processing your state updates_.

Comment: Yes, probably. The debugger shows that when the effect is called, both of the variables have the right values already. Never seen that before!

Answer (score 0):

React will wait for all of the code inside of an event handler to run before rerendering, so despite updating two pieces of state, you only have a single rerender happening.  You may have heard someone say "React reserves the right to update state asynchronously" - this is that in action.

https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates

Comment: I've heard someone say "React reserves the right to update state asynchronously," but to me that means asynchronously making 2 updates whenever it gets to them. It doesn't mean a _combined_ update whenever it gets to it, which is a little different.

Comment: @geneb. - This is a contrived example, but you can roughly think of it as `Promise.all(stateSetter1, stateSetter2).then(rerender)`.  React "knows" that there's multiple things going on because the event handler is synchronous - if you want them to not be batched, you can get clever and wrap the lower priority one in the success callback of a new promise.